# How can I refer a launchpad ppa in another?

Tags: ppa

To build the packages in my launchpad ppa, I want to use dev packages from another ppa.

Can I somehow do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is copy the package from the other ppa to your ppa, and mark the package as a dependant of your package.

You could also install the other ppa from the install script of your package, but that's not cool.